# Jenkins Windows 10: git-submodule cannot be used without a working tree

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, git-submodules

We have jenkins Windows 10 CI builder.

Our project has submodule, which I want to "git submodule update --init --recursive".

**This command is called from cmake script**, but even if one enables submodule processing the error will be the same:
**C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-submodule cannot be used without a working tree.**
[image]

Current setup copies all files of project from Ubuntu jenkins is run on( the setup is not known for sure and I started studying Jenkins from bottom ) and puts them into Windows CI builder into **Pull_Request_Builder_Winx64** folder.

Tried to run git manually from this folder: result is the same

Tried running update manually on the same project that is downloaded with git clone, it works.

Please help find the source of the issue, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the symlink in the path to workspace( C:/jenkins/workspace, "workspace" is symlink here that points to R:/workspace )

**Solution**: **Changed remote root directory in jenkins node configuration, so it contains no symlinks**( new path: R:/jenkins, path to workspace will be R:/jenkins/workspace )
[image]